# MapBox SDK - [ParseStyle]: Failed to parse style: 0 - Invalid value.

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I have implemented a owned map server from **OpenMapTiles Map Server**

My intention is to use the MapBox SDK with the maps of my server.

[image: Open Map Tile Server]

Apply the "Dark Matter" style using the following **TileJSON 2.0 specification**:

[image]

By using the setStyleJson method of MapBox I set this origin:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "access_token");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyleJson("http://192.168.1.65:8080/styles/dark-matter.json");
                mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(47.3769, 8.5417))
                        .zoom(25)
                        .build());
            }
        });
```

The map remains blank, and through the logcat I can see the following error message:

```
05-17 12:38:18.489 19008-19008/sergio.sanchez.sanchez.demomapbox E/mbgl: {chez.demomapbox}[ParseStyle]: Failed to parse style: 0 - Invalid value.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapboxMap.setStyleJson` method expects the actual JSON string, not a URL. In order to pass a URL, use mapbox map's `setStyleUrl` method or map view's `setStyleUrl` method:

```
mapView.setStyleUrl("http://192.168.1.65:8080/styles/dark-matter.json");
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: This solution also worked in a case where I called `new Style.Builder().fromJson()` with a URL.  I should have called `new Style.Builder().fromUrl()`.